# Multiply value of input type number and a number

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jsp-tags

I am facing a problem with jsp. I'm trying to multiply a number with value of input type number on dynamically when number is increased. 
I've following code.

```
<td data-th="Price"> ${prod.unitPrice }</td>
<td data-th="Quantity"><input type="number"class="form-control text-center" value="${item.quantity}"></td>
```

Above code will print the value which is passed in model. what will be best logic for obtaining new value when value is increased with UI. I need to display on subtotal

```
<td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">$......</td>
```

Comment: You can do it using javascript

Comment: I've tried but I got no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `tr` for provided `td`

I have added `class` for `tr` as well as `td`. added `onkeyup` event to input fields for changing input `quantity` to result in `Subtotal`

```
<tr class="data">
        <td data-th="Price" class="price"> ${prod.unitPrice}</td>
        <td data-th="Quantity"><input type="number" class="form-control text-center quantity" onkeyup="total(this);" value="${item.quantity}"></td>
        <td data-th="Subtotal" class="total" class="text-center"> ... </td>
</tr>
```

Following script will calculate the change depend on input `quantity` and set `sub total` on page load

```
//section for set sub total when page load
var r, i;
r = document.getElementsByClassName("data");
for(i=0;i<r.length; i++){
    r[i].getElementsByClassName("total")[0].innerHTML =
        r[i].getElementsByClassName("price")[0].innerText *
        r[i].getElementsByClassName("quantity")[0].value;
}


//function to update sub total when quantity changed
function total(element) {
    var tr = element.parentNode.parentNode;
    var price = tr.getElementsByClassName("price")[0].innerText;
    tr.getElementsByClassName("total")[0].innerHTML = price * element.value;
}

// function to sum all sub total
function sumTotal(){
  var tot = 0 ; //variable hold the sum
  var len = document.getElementsByClassName("total").length;
  for(var i =0; i<len; i++){ 
    tot += parseInt(document.getElementsByClassName("total")[i].innerText); 
  }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me 
now i am wondering what if I have to calculate total by adding all subtotal

Comment: @SangamJungGauli i have added to the answer, an extra function to sum of all sub total

Comment: `<td class="text-center ttotal" id="sumtot"><strong>.....</strong></td>`
this is for sum total

Comment: just put the `tot` value to the `sumtot`. e.g. `document.getElementById("sumtot").innerHTML = tot`